# How to make a very large skybox? (babylon.js)

Tags: babylonjs, skybox

How can I make a very large skybox?

Example:

```
var skybox = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("skyBox", 15000.0, this.scene);
```

The result is bad:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello you need to increase camera.maxZ to a value larger than your skybox.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I suggest is to reduce the scale factor of your spaceship and planet models. It seems that having a SkyBox size larger than 10000 causes the ugly texture seams/tearing of the Skybox at particular camera angles and distances. So bring everything down in scale if possible to make more room inside the limits of the Skybox perimeter.

Next try this: set `.infiniteDistance = true` to keep the Skybox away from the camera, and also set `.renderingGroupId = 0` on the Skybox. Lastly, set `.renderingGroupId = 1` or more, on all the models and objects to help stop them from disappearing *into thin air.*

```
var skybox = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox("skyBox", {size:10000.0}, 
this.scene);
skybox.infiniteDistance = true;
skybox.renderingGroupId = 0;
```

...and for models and sprite objects...

```
myModel.renderingGroupId = 1; /* greater than 0 */
```

These little tricks helped me to achieve a to-scale solar system simulation, but may not work in all cases.